# htaccess rewrite .htm to html not working

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website's .htaccess file I added the following rule to rewrite all requests with .htm extension to .html:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.html [NC]
```

Most of the URLs in my website were rewritten correctly but not the following URL. I don't know why this URL is not caught by the rewrite rule:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/view/186/4-test-limited.htm
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) argues that the file name extension should not be part of the URL. You might want to consider that before you go any further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to activate the mod_rewrite first.

**Try:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.html [R=permanent]
```

The `R=permanent` flag tells Apache to issue a permanent redirect 301 response, which is search-engine friendly.

Also, there are these great resources available online:

- [Tips for configuring Apache's mod_rewrite](http://www.xinsight.ca/blog/tips-for-configuring-apaches-mod_rewrite/)
- [modrewrite.com](http://www.modrewrite.com)
- [Learn Apache mod_rewrite: 13 Real-world Examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/)

Also worth checking:

- [10+ Mod_Rewrite Rules You Should Know](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html)

Comment: The mod_rewrite was already turned on, so I just add your rewrite Rule and works like a charm :) many thanks

Comment: RewriteBase / was missing